# How to return original inner text on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to randomize characters on hover for a specific id.
It works fine on mouse enter but can't get it stop and back to initial text when mouse leave.

Here's the code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
function text_shuffle() {
    "use strict";
    var counter = 0, all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var $_inter = setInterval(function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("text-shuffle");
        text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, counter) + all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length)) + text.innerHTML.substring(counter+1);
        counter = (counter+1)%text.innerHTML.length;
    }, 100);
}
$("#text-shuffle").mouseenter(text_shuffle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-shuffle">Home</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearInterval` to stop the randomize characters, replace the original text when mouse goes out of text.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
function text_shuffle() {
    "use strict";
    var counter = 0, all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
     $_inter = setInterval(function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("text-shuffle");
        text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, counter) + all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length)) + text.innerHTML.substring(counter+1);
        counter = (counter+1)%text.innerHTML.length;
    }, 100);
}
var value, $_inter;
$("#text-shuffle").mouseenter( function(){
   value  = $(this).html();
  text_shuffle();
  }).
  mouseout(function(){
  clearInterval($_inter);

    $(this).html(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-shuffle">Home</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your interval on mouseleave. You haven't called a mouseleave function so your code scrambles the chars inside your div indefinitely.

All I've done was set the interval to a variable and clear the variable on mouseleave.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  all = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var int;
  var counter = 0;
  
  function textShuffle() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text-shuffle");
    text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, counter) + all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length)) + text.innerHTML.substring(counter+1);
    counter = (counter+1)%text.innerHTML.length;
  }
  
  $("#text-shuffle").hover(function() {
     int = setInterval(textShuffle, 100);
    }, function () {
      clearInterval(int);
      document.getElementById("text-shuffle").innerText = "Home";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-shuffle">Home</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){

'use strict';

var all  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    elem = document.getElementById("text-shuffle"),
    orig = elem.innerHTML;

var $_inter;
function text_shuffle()
{ 
    var counter = 0;
    $_inter = setInterval( function()
    {
        elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.substring(0, counter) + all.charAt(( Math.random() * all.length ) | 0 ) + elem.innerHTML.substring(counter + 1);
        counter = (counter+1) % elem.innerHTML.length;
    }, 100);
}

function clear() { clearInterval( $_inter ); elem.innerHTML = orig };

$("#text-shuffle").hover( text_shuffle, clear )

}())
```